# Is there a way to store an array of Objects and the associated instance of another table in a single variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

I have two associated tables: Users and Posts. `Post` `belongs_to` `User`, so there is a foreign key `user_id` linking it to the Users table. 
Is there a way in which I can store an array of Post objects and its associated User object in a single variable?

```
@posts = Post.all
```

will return an array of all existing Posts, and

```
@user = Post.find(1).user
```

will return the first Post's corresponding User. Is there a way to combine these two queries in one?

If you are wondering why do I need this, I am working with ReactJS and I want to pass this variable as props so I can access the `User` attributes of a `Post` in my component.
Hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are after but if it's just the user associated with the first post then simply do:

```
@user = Post.first.user
```

If you want to iterate through each post to find the user then something like:

```
Posts.all.each do |post|
  @users << post.user      
end
```

If you want to just find the **first** post associated with each **user**, then ensure you have the relationship mapped correctly and iterate through each user instead:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

User.all.each do |user|
  @posts << user.posts.first
end
```

Comment: I am not proud of the way I phrased this question, but the answer I was looking for is actually the second piece of code you provided. Thank you, man.

Comment: just one question. What's the difference between `@users << post.user` and `@users = post.user`?

Comment: if you mean in the iteration then `@users = post.user` will just keep overwriting the `@users` array with the user associated with a post ... effectively on leaving the each block you will have the equivalent of `@users = Post.last.user`. doing `@users << post.user` will add a user on each iteration to the @users collection.